# Trying to play an MP3 through python with playsound. Not working

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

For context, I have a raspberry pi model4b, and an NFC reader attached to it. When the NFC reader detects a specific card, I want it to play a specific audio file.

I have used playsound, pygame and pydub (after installign their libraries) and I keep on getting errors. Here is my play.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# import required module
from playsound import playsound

# for playing note.wav file
playsound('file.mp3')
print('playing sound using  playsound')
```

this is my full error:

```
pi@tjobbe:~/storytime $ sudo python play.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "play.py", line 3, in <module>
    from playsound import playsound
ImportError: No module named playsound
```

I get the same using

```
sudo python3 play.py
```

Even when the code is stripped back to its bare minimum I get the same error:

```
import playsound
playsound('file.mp3')
```

Comment: Do you have multiple Python environments on your computer? You may have installed `playsound` for a different Python version.

Comment: How would I check? I have tried using sudo python3 play.py and even sudo python play.py as well as just python3 play.py and python play.py

Comment: first check version `python3 -V` and `pip3 -V` or simply use `python3 -m pip install playsound` to install it in correct Python

Answer (score 0):

Try running `python -m pip install playsound`

if you do not have pip installed aleady, run `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

(or `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` if you are using Python3)